# Free Software Version Control (3-4 man)

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I'd need help for finding a program for software version control with following features:
- Multiplataform (Windows and Ubuntu)
- Keep our code private (perfect if support private ftp repositories).
- Free or cheap for small groups (3-4).
- We dont need a big storage capacity
- (Optional) Eclipse integration
- Automatic notification of updates

We tried Bazaar, it enforces all the rules except the last one, because for password protected repositories sources it only update on demand (asking the password all the times)

Thanks in advance

Comment: git? Tons of material here on SO about it

Comment: I'm unclear why you can't use bazaar, is it because you need to give a password all the time? (this can be fixed). What do you mean with "only update on demand" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Git is now the [official VCS used by all Eclipse projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335804/confusion-in-choosing-between-javagit-jgit-and-egit/5335941#5335941), it would be a nice fit.

The latest Eclipse Indogo 3.7 comes with **[EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/)** included: no need to "install" Git.
As this [SO answer illustrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302089/git-plugin-for-eclipse/1182803#1182803), it is fairly complete.

[image: EGit repositories view]

Answer (score 3):

I personally love [subverion](http://subversion.tigris.org/). It fulfills all your criteria

Comment: the subclipse plugin for Eclipse works great, the team sync view is perfect
http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=9A92093E118F1B1420C1CDAD0D08E76D?pageID=p4wYuA

Answer (score 1):

**Git, Subversion**... Eclipse integration is a job for Eclipse, i.e. some plugin.

Git is more powerfull but takes longer to learn.

You always get e-mail when commit happens. Although it's hard form me to imagine why you want to be distracted everytime any of your colleagues does a commit.

Answer (score 0):

We use Git to manage large files and projects. The Git version control system offers a fantastic set of features for completing writing projects in a fast, efficient and organized way. If you're a professional software developer, then you should be using version control software to manage your projects. Here's a great [comparison of version control software](http://www.timedoctor.com/biz3.0/git-mecurial-and-cvs-comparison-of-svn-software/) so you can decide the best solution for you.