# Automatic prune with Git fetch or pull

Tags: git

If someone deleted a remote branch because the work is over and I don't know, I won't do a `git fetch --prune` and eventually I will push back the deleted branch.

Is there a viable solution for forcing Git to use the prune mode when fetching / pulling without having to specify it every time?

Comment: You will soon (git 1.8.5, Q4 2013) be able to specify in the local config of a repo that you want to *always* prune on `git fetch`! See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18718936/6309)

Answer (score 523, accepted):

[Since git 1.8.5 (Q4 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bb80ee09974667a1db6bbc5e33574ed869b76a88/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L99-L101):

> "`git fetch`" (hence "`git pull`" as well) learned to check "`fetch.prune`" and "`remote.*.prune`" configuration variables and to behave as if the "`--prune`" command line option was given.

That means that, if you set remote.origin.prune to true:

```
git config remote.origin.prune true
```

Any `git fetch` or `git pull` will automatically prune.

Note: Git 2.12 (Q1 2017) will fix a bug related to this configuration, which would make `git remote rename` misbehave.
See "[How do I rename a git remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41990354/6309)".

---

See more at [commit 737c5a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/737c5a9cde708d6995c765b7c2e95033edd0a896):

> Without "`git fetch --prune`", remote-tracking branches for a branch the other side already has removed will stay forever.
>   Some people want to always run "`git fetch --prune`".
>
> To accommodate users who want to either prune always or when fetching from a particular remote, add two new configuration variables "`fetch.prune`" and "`remote.<name>.prune`":
>
> - "`fetch.prune`" allows to enable prune for all fetch operations.
> - "`remote.<name>.prune`" allows to change the behaviour per remote.
>
> The latter will naturally override the former, and the `--[no-]prune` option from the command line will override the configured default.
>
> Since `--prune` is a potentially destructive operation (Git doesn't keep reflogs for deleted references yet), we don't want to prune without users consent, so this configuration will not be on by default.

Comment: I want this behavior by default in all my git repos. Is there some where I can put this in my .gitconfig to make that happen?

Comment: @Andrew a good start would be `git config --global fetch.prune true`

Comment: what are the possible downsides to always pruning on pull? the quote mentions that reflog history is affected... but what practical problem might that introduce?

Comment: @Grapho no real downside but... see more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862779/6309

Answer (score 267):

## `git config --global fetch.prune true`

To always `--prune` for `git fetch` and `git pull` in all your Git repositories:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

This above command appends in your global Git configuration (typically `~/.gitconfig`) the following lines. Use `git config -e --global` to view your global configuration.

```
[fetch]
    prune = true
```

---

## `git config remote.origin.prune true`

To always `--prune` but from one single repository:

```
git config remote.origin.prune true
                 #^^^^^^
                 #replace with your repo name
```

This above command adds in your local Git configuration (typically `.git/config`) the below last line. Use `git config -e` to view your local configuration.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    prune = true
```

You can also use `--global` within the second command or use instead `--local` within the first command.

---

## `git config --global gui.pruneDuringFetch true`

If you use `git gui` you may also be interested by:

```
git config --global gui.pruneDuringFetch true
```

that appends:

```
[gui]
    pruneDuringFetch = true
```

---

## References

The corresponding documentations from [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> #### `--global`
>
> For writing options: write to global `~/.gitconfig` file rather than the repository `.git/config`, write to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` file if this file exists and the `~/.gitconfig` file doesn’t.

> #### `--local`
>
> For writing options: write to the repository `.git/config` file. This is the default behavior.

> #### `fetch.prune`
>
> If true, fetch will automatically behave as if the `--prune` option was given on the command line. See also `remote.<name>.prune`.

> #### `gui.pruneDuringFetch`
>
> "true" if [git-gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) should prune remote-tracking branches when performing a fetch. The default value is "false".

> #### `remote.<name>.prune`
>
> When set to true, fetching from this remote by default will also remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote (as if the `--prune` option was given on the command line). Overrides `fetch.prune` settings, if any.

Comment: Side note: I just learned about `git config -e` and `git config -e --global` from this post. No more typing `vim` commands to point to a specific path to a git config file, and having to think about what that specific path is.

Comment: This answer is quite thorough, but very hard to read because of its formatting. I’d have found "To always --prune for git fetch and git pull in all your Git repositories: `git config --global fetch.prune true`" just as good (with a link to the relevant docs).

Answer (score 21):

If you want to always `prune` when you `fetch`, I can suggest to use [Aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases).

Just type `git config -e` to open your editor and change the configuration for a specific project and add a section like

```
[alias]
pfetch = fetch --prune
```

the when you fetch with `git pfetch` the prune will be done automatically.

Comment: I understand. Pull by the way will use git fetch and not git pfetch... should I directly have an alias for pull?

Comment: I will. In this way you have both options, normal `pull` and `fetch` and their pruned version. Actually, I think (but I haven't tried) you can write `fetch = fetch --prune` directly in the alias section and therefore `pull` will use the pruned fetch automatically

Comment: As far as I know `fetch = fetch --prune` doesn't work, overwriting a command with an alias did not work for me. This could be because I'm using an old version (1.7.2.5)

Comment: From the git config documentation: "To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored."

Answer (score 3):

> and eventually I will push back the deleted branch

This is something that I think you should address. If you have git configured so that it pushes branches you aren't trying to push, this can be a problem. I personally prefer to set it up so that I only push a branch when I explicitly specify a branch that I want to push.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/948397/3753318 for some guidance on how to configure the push settings in your git repository.