# I removed remote branch in GIT but other clients still see this branch

Tags: git, git-branch

In GIT I removed remote branch:

```
git push origin :my_removed_branch
```

But if other client will do this:

```
git branch -a
```

He will see the removed branch.

```
...
remotes/origin/master    
remotes/origin/my_removed_branch
```

How do I get other customers stopped to see the removed branch?

Git version: 1.9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @hauleth's answer that you need to prune.

If you want to perform automatic pruning when performing a git pull or fetch you may want to read this stackoverflow answer in regards to [automatically having branches pruned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308535/automatic-prune-with-git-fetch-or-pull) without having to manually call it

Answer (score 1):

He need to run `git fetch --prune` to delete all branches that doesn't have their counterparts on server.