# Git merge develop into feature branch outputs "Already up-to-date" while it's not

Tags: git, merge

I checked out a feature branch from develop called `branch-x`. After a while other people pushed changes to the develop branch.

I want to merge those changes into my `branch-x`. However if I do

```
git merge develop
```

it says "Already up-to-date" and doesn't allow me to merge.

`git diff develop` shows that there are differences between `branch-x` and develop.

How do I merge develop into `branch-x`?

Comment: Is your branch really latest? Pull sometimes fails. Try `git checkout develop` `git merge origin/develop`

Comment: Yes, "git merge origin/develop" outputs "Already up-to-date".

Answer (score 142):

You should first [`pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) the changes from the `develop` branch and only then merge them to your branch:

```
git checkout develop 
git pull 
git checkout branch-x
git rebase develop
```

Or, when on `branch-x`:

```
git fetch && git rebase origin/develop
```

---

I have an alias that saves me a lot of time. Add to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    fr = "!f() { git fetch && git rebase origin/"$1"; }; f"
```

Now, all that you have to do is:

```
git fr develop
```

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't described it in my question, but I already did pull the changes to my local machine. So this isn't causing the issue.

Comment: Mindless use of `git rebase` is dangerous. It may easily create nonsensical commits that won't compile.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica but, it can be a mess if your current branch already have commits and you want to  'squash' some commits after a merge, so rebase would be better in this scenario

Comment: It broke my commits as well.

Comment: What exactly was broken?

Comment: broke my commits as well.

Comment: Why would I use rebase instead git merge on the last line of the first list of commands? wouldn't merge do the same but retain git history better? I never understand rebase properly, that's why I ask.

Comment: Much better to use git merge than this approach. Problems with commits were already mentioned. I want to add that I experienced it myself as well. On the other hand, using git merge worked like a charm.

Answer (score 87):

Step by step self explaining commands for update of feature branch with the latest code from origin "develop" branch:

```
git checkout develop
git pull -p
git checkout feature_branch
git merge develop
```

If there are any merge conflicts after "git merge" CMD, fix the merge issues manually & add those manually merged file(s) & commit

```
git add <mergedFile>
git commit -m "Merged develop to feature_branch"
```

Finally push the merge to remote:

```
git push origin feature_branch
```

Comment: What does the `-p` option do? I can't find it in my manpage.

Comment: Just commit whatever you have in your feature_branch and then try this answer.

Comment: git pull -p
-p is the same as --prune, this option do cleaning of outdated branches. You could define automatic prune instead usage of parameter:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308535/automatic-prune-with-git-fetch-or-pull

In the example above -p option could not be used.

Comment: If there are any merge conflicts after "git merge develop" CMD, fix the merge issues & add those manually merged file using "git add <mergedFile>". Then commit the changes "git commit -m "Merged develop to feature_branch" & then execute last CMD to push changes to origin feature_branch. Could not edit the answer due to "Suggested edit que is full" error.

Comment: @Saurabhcdt you can edit now

Comment: None of theses solutions worked for me either.  If I do a compare between develop and feature branch, expected changes are shown.  But when I do a merge using VS 2022 or manually, nothing changes.  Had to manually update one script to hopefully get past issue.

Comment: Instead of switching branch to develop then back to branch, replace the first 3 lines with this `git fetch origin develop:develop`

Answer (score 20):

```
git pull origin develop
```

Since pulling a branch into another directly merges them together

Answer (score 16):

```
git fetch && git merge origin/develop
```

Comment: 'git pull origin develop' is an equivalent

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way. Thank you.

Comment: For those wondering what the difference between this and checking out to develop > pulling latest > checking out to branch-x > merging develop is, is that this merges the latest develop without updating the local develop branch.

Answer (score 6):

Initially my repo said "Already up to date."

```
MINGW64 (feature/Issue_123) 
$ git merge develop
```

Output:

```
Already up to date.
```

But the code is not up to date & it is showing some differences in some files.

```
MINGW64 (feature/Issue_123)
$ git diff develop
```

Output:

```
diff --git 
a/src/main/database/sql/additional/pkg_etl.sql 
b/src/main/database/sql/additional/pkg_etl.sql
index ba2a257..1c219bb 100644
--- a/src/main/database/sql/additional/pkg_etl.sql
+++ b/src/main/database/sql/additional/pkg_etl.sql
```

However, merging fixes it.

```
MINGW64 (feature/Issue_123)
$ git merge origin/develop
```

Output:

```
Updating c7c0ac9..09959e3
Fast-forward
3 files changed, 157 insertions(+), 92 deletions(-)
```

Again I have confirmed this by using `diff` command.

```
MINGW64 (feature/Issue_123)
$ git diff develop
```

No differences in the code now!