# How do I rename a git remote?

Tags: git

I currently have a git remote called `heroku` and I'd like to rename it to `production`.

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/example.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/example.git (push)
```

Answer (score 205, accepted):

```
$ git remote rename <old-name> <new-name>
```

So, for this example:

```
$ git remote rename heroku production
```

Useful docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#renaming-a-remote-repository

Comment: Having a warning not knowing the consequences: warning: `Not updating non-default fetch refspec
        +refs/*:refs/*
        Please update the configuration manually if necessary.`  Would you understand this warning and know what should be done in that case ?

Answer (score 10):

Be aware that until Git 2.11, [`git remote rename`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) might try to rename a non-existing remote!

That is fixed in Git 2.12 (Q1 2017): See [commit e459b07](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e459b073fb3ab8abe36e6bee5c5d6be1ed3928ae), [commit af5bacf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af5bacf471825662f8eeda932cfabd6c47634434) (19 Jan 2017) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fe575f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe575f06532bde1e672a2313fd76ef09b66fc355), 31 Jan 2017)</sup>

> ### `remote rename`: more carefully determine whether a remote is configured
>
> With anticipatory tweaking for remotes defined in `~/.gitconfig` (e.g. "`remote.origin.prune`" set to `true`, even though there may or
>   may not actually be "`origin`" remote defined in a particular Git
>   repository), "`git remote rename`" and other commands misinterpreted
>   and behaved as if such a non-existing remote actually existed.

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), "[`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) `rename X Y`" needs to adjust configuration variables (e.g. `branch.<name>.remote`) whose value used to be `X` to `Y`.
`branch.<name>.pushRemote` is now also updated.

See [commit b3fd6cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3fd6cbf29435f8b49a0a5d9f86236e00b084624) (01 Feb 2020), and [commit f2a2327](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2a2327a4a6a9bccade6df2bed1fdc3a8ab37f4c), [commit 923d4a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/923d4a5ca4f86c19247ef436e6d03d261ebce904), [commit ceff1a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ceff1a13084bba74b607d738c6c467365aa6a5f7), [commit 1a83068](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a83068c26206d2b45718e0896955eb61bef8353), [commit 88f8576](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88f8576eda2880587fb4487ba469d909dbe35a7b) (27 Jan 2020) by [Bert Wesarg (`bertwesarg`)](https://github.com/bertwesarg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d0038f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0038f4b31d6ab1f0602a4d3c19e35c5004175fa), 25 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`remote rename/remove`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/923d4a5ca4f86c19247ef436e6d03d261ebce904): handle branch..pushRemote config values
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Bert Wesarg</sup>
>
> When renaming or removing a remote with
>
> ```
> git remote rename X Y
> git remote remove X
> ```
>
> Git already renames/removes any config values from
>
> ```
> branch.<name>.remote = X
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> branch.<name>.remote = Y
> ```
>
> As branch..pushRemote also names a remote, it now also renames or removes these config values from
>
> ```
> branch.<name>.pushRemote = X
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> branch.<name>.pushRemote = Y
> ```

And:

> ### [`remote rename/remove`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3fd6cbf29435f8b49a0a5d9f86236e00b084624): gently handle `remote.pushDefault` config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Bert Wesarg</sup>
>
> When renaming a remote with
>
> ```
> git remote rename X Y
> git remote remove X
> ```
>
> Git already renames or removes any `branch.<name>.remote` and branch.`<name>.pushRemote` configurations if their value is `X`.
>
> However `remote.pushDefault` needs a more gentle approach, as this may be set in a non-repo configuration file.
>   In such a case only a warning is printed, such as:
>
> ```
> warning: The global configuration remote.pushDefault in:
>  $HOME/.gitconfig:35
> now names the non-existent remote origin
> ```
>
> It is changed to `remote.pushDefault = Y` or removed when set in a repo configuration though.

Comment: I had always been wondering whether renaming a remote is "truly safe" since a remote name appears literally in dozens of places in the config file. I guess I now know the answer... need a recent git.

Comment: Frankly it would have probably been a safer design if remotes had a (SHA-style) id and possibly any number of convenience aliases. But I guess that would have made the config files somewhat less "human readable".

Answer (score 10):

A common use case is to switch `origin` to your fork and rename the current `origin` to `upstream`.

A simple remote rename will leave `pushDefault` and `branch` config values pointing towards the renamed remote and not at origin as is generally intended. If you are doing this, then this flow will work best...

First get the current `origin`:

```
git remote -v
```

Record the value (`OLD_URL`) and now change it with `set-url` followed by adding the old `origin` as a new `upstream`:

```
git remote set-url origin NEW_URL
git remote add upstream OLD_URL
```

Answer (score -1):

As you linked and said yourself in your answer, you just have to type

`git remote rename heroku production`

see bottom of the page: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: It is allowed to self-answer questions.  Is you answer so much better it warranted a new answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was just confused if he was answering himself or if he was kind of asking for confirmation. I didn't know that one could answer his own questions.