# How to set git to prune on pull globally

Tags: git

With the command:

```
git config remote.origin.prune true
```

you can configure a repo to automatically prune on every pull request [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308535/automatic-prune-with-git-fetch-or-pull).

I always want this option to be set.  Does anyone know a way to set this globally for all repos' remote origins or is the only option to perform it per repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git config --global fetch.prune true` will prune all repos

Comment: Of course!  Should not have missed this obvious solution--thanks!