# Git remove origin/branch in git log

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have done some updates on a branch and merge it to master.
But it seems I've done a mistake, and I do not know how to fix it.

`git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` give this :

```
*   85b7966 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #2 from doom-fr/improve-documentation
|\  
| * 547f135 (origin/improve-documentation) Improve documentation : add linux installation instructions
|/  
*   66dac19 Merge pull request #1
```

I think that **`(origin/improve-documentation)`** should not be there.

How can I remove it ?

Comment: Use `--no-decorate`

Answer (score 2):

What you described and what your git log command shows makes perfect sense.

`origin/improve-documentation` marks where the improve-documentation branch has been pointing to on your remote repository, the last time you connected to it with a git command.

If you want it to disappear you need to ensure 2 things:

1. The `improve-documentation` branch must be deleted on GitHub (or what else remote repo you are using)
2. When updating your local master branch again, use `git pull --prune` to tell git to discard all local pointers to remote branches which do not exist anymore (this is not done by default).

As explained in [Automatic prune with Git fetch or pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308535/automatic-prune-with-git-fetch-or-pull) you can also make pruning the default behavior locally for your specific remote via

```
git config remote.origin.prune true
```

or globally for every git repo you use

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

Comment: To make pruning the *default* default (for everything), use `git config --global fetch.prune true`. Configuring locally for one remote only configures that one remote for that one repository. (This is of course fine, if that's what you want!)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it correctly ,you want to undo the commit **`547f135 (origin/improve-documentation)`** that was merged to master branch.

Create a branch off of `master`and run `git revert <commit-hash>`.
This will create a new commit and undo all the changes that were done as part of the wrong commit.

You can identify the commit hash by `git log`

So you can do

> **git revert 547f135**

and then try to merge this branch again to master.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly sketchy option would be to simply reset `master`. **Only do this with the knowledge and consent of other people using `origin`!**

```
git switch master  # if necessary
git reset 66dac19
git push -f
```

This will leave 85b7966 as an orphaned commit that will eventually be garbage-collected. It will also confuse anyone who has already seen 85b7966 and is unaware of what you have done, hence the warning in bold.