# Do I need to run a git fetch to see all remote branches with git branch -r?

Tags: git

Do I need to run a git fetch to see all remote branches with git branch -r ?

Or in other words: does a git branch -r execute a remote call, or only the known remote branches are displayed?

Comment: No remote call when calling `git branch -r`. so **yes**, you need to fetch to be able to see new branches (or movement of branches).

Comment: Disable your network connection then run various Git commands to learn which of them contacts the remote repository and which do not. `fetch`, `push`, `pull`, `ls-remote` and probably a couple more need to contact the remote to do their job. Most Git commands operate only on the local repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but check the [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) used for your remote:

```
git config --get remote.origin.fetch
```

You should see:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

That would fetch all remote branches.

A refspec like `+refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev` would only fetch and update the 'dev' remote tracking branch.

Answer (score 1):

`git branch` does not perform any network requests and will only show the currently known state of your local remote-tracking branches.

But it is also possible to view the branches of a remote repository with [`git ls-remote --heads`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html#Documentation/git-ls-remote.txt---heads), which performs a network request without updating your local remote-tracking branches.

Answer (score 0):

`git branch -r` doesn't execute a remote call, it only lists the remote tracking branches you have locally. (see the folder ´.git/refs/remotes´)

Note that `git branch -r` also will list a lot of remote branches which haven't existed for quite a long time unless you add the `--prune` argument to you `pull` and `fetch` commands. (or you could [change the settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18718936/1978365) to always prune when fetching.)